# Chain of Observables emitting same Observable when done

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm looking to do this in rxjs:

- I have a N number of http calls;
- I want to fire these calls **sequentially**;
- I want to map the result of each call into a Observable stream of InfoMessage;

Non-working pseudo-code:

```
class InfoMessage {
  constructor(public message: string) {}
}

doAllRequests() : Observable<InfoMessage> {
    return Observable.create((obs: Observer<InfoMessage>) => {
      doRequest("http://test1.com").map((res: RxRequestResponse) => obs.next(new InfoMessage("request1 done")));
      doRequest("http://test2.com").map((res: RxRequestResponse) => obs.next(new InfoMessage("request2")));
      doRequest("http://test3.com").map((res: RxRequestResponse) => obs.next(new InfoMessage("request3")));
      obs.complete();
    });
  }

doRequest(url: string) : Observable<RxRequestResponse> {
  // use some http client which is wrapped in an Observable of type RxRequestResponse
}

doAllRequests().subscribe(next => console("Message: " + next.message));
```

**Update** suggested answer by Martin:
Your answer seems to work, but only if I subscribe to the first request like so:

```
Observable.create((observer: Observer<InfoMessage>) => {
  doRequest("http://test1.com")
    .do(response => observer.next(new InfoMessage("request1 done")))
    .concatMap(() => doRequest("http://test2.com"))
    .do(response => observer.next(new InfoMessage("request2")))
    .concatMap(() => doRequest("http://test3.com"))
    .do(response => {
      observer.next(new InfoMessage("request3"));
      observer.complete();
    }).subscribe();
})
```

And I really like to postpone subscribing and leave that to the caller of the doAllRequests(). Any thoughts?

**Update**: suggested answer by Quentin

That solution works and it scales better for huge scripts I am going to run (with numerous requests), in terms of verbosity of code (or rather lack thereof).

Since that is the one I now end up using, I'm changing my accepted answer. But Martin, I do feel guilty about that. I still have an upvote for you ... we good?

Comment: So you want to receive each response in the observer immediately when it completes and then start the next http call.

Comment: @martin yessir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `doRequest()` already return an observable, why don't do you try to combine all your requests and get the responses into a single stream? You could use a forkJoin for that:

```
doAllRequests() : Observable<InfoMessage> {
 return forkJoin(
  doRequest("http://test1.com"),
  doRequest("http://test2.com"),
  doRequest("http://test3.com")
 ).pipe(
  mergeMap((responsesArray: any[]) => from(responsesArray)),
  map((response: any) => new InfoMessage(response))
 );
}
this.doAllRequests().subscribe();
```

Comment: I really like how this code looks. Thanks for answering, I'm trying this tomorrow.

Comment: I wrote the code using the last version of rxjs with the pipeable operators, but I am sure you can figure out how to write it in your current version. 
Don't forget that, in order for the forkJoin operator to emit, all the observables you pass to the forkJoin have to complete (since it is requests, I assume they all complete).

Comment: Tried it and using it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If each HTTP call is independent on the result of the previous call you can just chain them with `concatMap`:

```
Observable.create((observer: Observer<InfoMessage>) => {
  doRequest("http://test1.com")
    .do(response => observer.next(new InfoMessage("request1 done")))
    .concatMap(() => doRequest("http://test2.com"))
    .do(response => observer.next(new InfoMessage("request2")))
    .concatMap(() => doRequest("http://test3.com"))
    .do(response => {
      observer.next(new InfoMessage("request3"));
      observer.complete();
    });
})
```

Just don't forget you need to return `Observable.create` from your function and subscribe to it.

Comment: I'm trying that out and let you know. Thanks in advance. The "return" was indeed suppose to be in my example.

Comment: Updated my question after trying it out

Comment: Yeah that's true, you need to subscribe but it doesn't matter because the callback to `Observable.create` is called only after this Observable is subscribed